# Mudar Nome de Uma String em um Vetor de Estruturas

Tags: c

Boa tarde galera, to travando em uma parte do meu código e realmente não sei a lógica para resolver ele.

Se o nome do fabricante do vetor `carros` na posição `j` for igual `Chevrolet`, mude ele para `GM`.

```
for(j = 0; j < qtd; j++) {
    if(carros[j].fabricante == "Chevrolet") {
       carros[j].fabricante = "GM";
    }
}
```

Comment: *lembrando que essa é a única parte do código que está dando erro, se precisarem do código todo, me avisem.

Answer (score 2):

Utilize a função [`strcmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcmp.html). Adicionalmente, você precisa utilizar a função [`strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strcpy.html) para fazer a atribuição do valor `GM`. Ambas são definidas no cabeçalho `string.h`

```
for (j = 0; j < qtd; j++) {
    if (strcmp(carros[j].fabricante, "Chevrolet") == 0) {
       strcpy(carros[j].fabricante, "GM");
    }
}
```

Comment: Brigadão mercador :D